# Running Total to the latest period

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cumulative-sum, ansi-sql

I want to query the table so that the running total is repeatedly
carrying over to the latest period as long as the value dose not fall to 0.
Assuming I have a table with values as such below:

| Name | Period | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 02/2022 | 2 |
| A | 03/2022 | 5 |
| A | 04/2022 | 3 |
| A | 05/2022 | 7 |
| B | 02/2022 | 9 |
| B | 04/2022 | 6 |

I want my result to be:

```
| Name | Period | Value|
| A| 02/2022| 2 |
| A| 03/2022| 7 |
| A| 04/2022| 10|
| A| 05/2022| 17|
| B| 02/2022| 9 |
| B| 03/2022| 9 |
| B| 04/2022| 15|
| B| 05/2022| 15|
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT 
    PERIOD
    ,NAME
    ,SUM(SUM(Value)) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY PERIOD) AS balance
  FROM 
    table

 WHERE Period < CURRENT_DATE()
 GROUP BY 
   1
   ,2
```

This results in the value stopping at the latest period the activity occurred as such:

```
| Name | Period | Value|
| A    | 02/2022| 2    |
| A    | 03/2022| 7    |
| A    | 04/2022| 10   |
| A    | 05/2022| 17   |
| B    | 02/2022| 9    |
| B    | 04/2022| 15   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you haven't had an answer in a full day so even though I work in TSQL I'll try a solution that's ANSI SQL compatible. Work with me if my syntax is off a bit.

Before we start, check your "Desired Output", you're currently showing a running total for A on 3/22 of 5, but you had a 2 for A on 2/22 so it should be a running total of 7, right?

Anyway, assuming that's just a typo, I'd approach this by making a few CTEs that build a list of all {PERIOD, NAME} pairs you want reported, then JOIN your actual data to that. There are a number of ways to generate the dates, the easiest is to use DISTINCT if your actual data is fairly robust, but I can describe other methods if that assumption does not hold for your data.

So with all that in mind, here is my solution. I put your sample data in a CTE for portability, just replace my "cteTabA" with whatever your data table is really named

```
--Code sample data as a CTE for portability
;with cteTabA as ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM ( VALUES 
        ('A', '02/2022', '2')
        , ('A', '03/2022', '5')
        , ('A', '04/2022', '3')
        , ('A', '05/2022', '7')
        , ('B', '02/2022', '9')
        , ('B', '04/2022', '6')
    ) as TabA(Name, Period, Value) 
) --END of sample data, actual query below
--First, build a list of periods to use. If your data set is full, just select DISTINCT
, cteDates as ( --but there are other ways if this doesn't work for you - let me know!
    SELECT DISTINCT Period FROM cteTabA
) --Next, build a list of names to report on
, cteNames as (
    SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM cteTabA
) --Now build your table that has all periods for all names
, cteRepOn as (
    SELECT * FROM cteNames CROSS JOIN cteDates 
)--Now assemble a table that has entries for each period for each name,
--but fill in zeroes for those you don't actually have data for
, cteFullList as (
    SELECT L.*, COALESCE(D.Value, 0) as Value
    FROM cteRepOn as L 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cteTabA as D on L.Name = D.Name AND L.Period = D.Period 
)--Now your query works as expected with the gaps filled in
SELECT PERIOD, NAME, Value 
    ,SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY PERIOD) AS balance
FROM  cteFullList
WHERE Period < '06/2022'--CURRENT_DATE()
ORDER BY NAME, PERIOD
```

This produces an output as follows

| PERIOD | NAME | Value | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/2022 | A | 2 | 2 |
| 03/2022 | A | 5 | 7 |
| 04/2022 | A | 3 | 10 |
| 05/2022 | A | 7 | 17 |
| 02/2022 | B | 9 | 9 |
| 03/2022 | B | 0 | 9 |
| 04/2022 | B | 6 | 15 |
| 05/2022 | B | 0 | 15 |